# Action taken when Enter key is pressed. But nothing happens. No errors

Tags: c#, enter

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        DialogResult dResult;

        dResult = MessageBox.Show("You have entered: " + textBox1.Text, "Message Box Info", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        label1.Text = "You clicked " + dResult.ToString();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1_Click(this, KeyEventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

This is my code to see if the enter key was pressed on a text box, and i want it to click the button when the enter key is pressed. I run the program, and nothing happens. Im new to C# as you can tell. Any help or comments would be helpful. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: F9 for breakpoints or look in the Debug menu in Visual Studio (assuming it's VS!)

Comment: I've edited your question, see why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely refactor your code the way pcnThird did it, but I recreated your code in an otherwise empty WinForms app and it worked just fine, even with passing `KeyEventArgs.Empty`.

The way you've got it, the code *should* run.

I suspect your `KeyDown` event is not actually attached to `textBox1_KeyDown`.

Check your properties window at design-time to make sure it's actually attached.

[image]

Or temporarily, type the following into your form's constructor:

```
this.textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a shared method:

```
public void SharedMethod()
{
    DialogResult dResult;

    dResult = MessageBox.Show("You have entered: " + textBox1.Text, "Message Box Info", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    label1.Text = "You clicked " + dResult.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    SharedMethod();
}

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        SharedMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: `KeyEventArgs.Empty` refers to the static `Empty` field declared on `EventArgs` - ideally the field should be referenced using the base class but that's not a big issue (or the code wouldn't compile). Since `EventArgs.Empty` is simply `EventArgs` you can use this for any event

Comment: @Charleh, I hadn't noticed the OP used `KeyEventArgs.Empty` before I posted my answer. My bad!

Comment: No probs, I like this answer since it's DRY